# Populate the list based on which datacenter code is running on

Tags: java, linked-list, enum, set

*This is a follow on to : [Efficiently detect datacenter based on server hostname and return the full path](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/89938/efficiently-detect-datacenter-based-on-server-hostname-and-return-the-full-path).*

I have a library which is running in different datacenters in production. I have three datacenters in production:

```
DHP, SLP, LTR
```

Depending on which datacenter code is running, I need to make a LinkedList (`allPaths`) which will have local datacenter path and then followed by remote datacenter path. As an example, if my code is running in DHP datacenter, then `allPaths` linked list will have. First element will always be LOCAL datacenter where the code is running and remaining can be other datacenter as per enum.

```
/tr/datacenter/dhp
/tr/datacenter/slp
/tr/datacenter/ltr
```

Our machine name is like this in production and it is also possible that machine hostname can have more dots in between separated by another domain in future.

```
dbx111.dhp.host.com (machine in dhp datacenter)
dbx112.slp.host.com (machine in slp datacenter)
dcx113.ltr.host.com (machine in ltr datacenter)
```

And our machine name in `DEV` (our dev environment) is like this and this is DEV datacenter.

```
z-wejnv-0432.dev.host.com
```

Below are my use case:

For code running in production case and if the `DataFlowEnum` is `PARTIAL`:

- If it is running in `DHP` datacenter, then `LOCAL_PATH` should be `/tr/datacenter/dhp` and `REMOTE_PATH` SET will be `/tr/datacenter/slp` and `/tr/datacenter/ltr`.
- Similarly If it is running in `SLP` datacenter, then `LOCAL_PATH` should be `/tr/datacenter/slp` and `REMOTE_PATH` will be `/tr/datacenter/dhp` and `/tr/datacenter/ltr`.
- Similarly If it is running in `LTR` datacenter, then `LOCAL_PATH` should be `/tr/datacenter/ltr` and `REMOTE_PATH` will be `/tr/datacenter/dhp` and `/tr/datacenter/slp`.

For code running in production case and if the `DataFlowEnum` is `TEMP` everything is same as above - Only difference is instead of `tr`, I will use `trpp` and all the logic is same.

If the code is not running in production or it is running in `DEV` datacenter, then `LOCAL_PATH` and `REMOTE_PATH` should always be `/tr/datacenter/dhp` if `DataFlowType` is `PARTIAL` or `/trpp/datacenter/dhp` if `DataFlowType` is `TEMP`.

Below is my `DataCenterEnum`:

```
public enum DatacenterEnum {
    DHP("/datacenter/dhp"), SLP("/datacenter/slp"), LTR("/datacenter/ltr");

    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final DatacenterEnum[] VALUES = values();
    private static final int SIZE = VALUES.length;
    private static final DatacenterEnum ourLocation = findLocation();
    private static final String LOCAL_PATH = ourLocation.findLocalPath();
    private static final Set<String> REMOTE_PATH = ourLocation.findRemotePath();

    private String value;

    private DatacenterEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static String forCode(int code) {
        return (code >= 0 && code < SIZE) ? VALUES[code].name() : null;
    }

    private static DatacenterEnum findLocation() {
        Optional<String> ourhost = getHostNameOfServer();

        if (ourhost.isPresent()) {
            if (isDevHost(ourhost.get())) {
                return DHP;
            }
            for (DatacenterEnum dc : VALUES) {
                String namepart = "." + dc.name().toLowerCase() + ".";
                if (ourhost.get().indexOf(namepart) >= 0) {
                    return dc;
                }
            }

            // this means the call is coming from some other datacenter apart from DHP, SLP and LTR, 
            // so we will randomly select DHP, SLP or LTR
            return DataUtils.isProduction() ? VALUES[random.nextInt(SIZE)] : DHP;
        }

        // if it comes here then it means somehow, we failed to find the hostname.
        // so we will randomly select DHP, SLP or LTR           
        return DataUtils.isProduction() ? VALUES[random.nextInt(SIZE)] : DHP;
    }

    private String findLocalPath() {
        String path = DatacenterEnum.DHP.value();
        if (DataUtils.isProduction()) {
            path = ourLocation.value();
        }
        return path;
    }

    private Set<String> findRemotePath() {
        Set<String> remotePath = new HashSet<String>();
        if (DataUtils.isProduction()) {
            // contains all DatacenterEnum except ourLocation
            Set<DatacenterEnum> remoteSet = EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(ourLocation));
            for (DatacenterEnum dc : remoteSet) {
                remotePath.add(dc.value());
            }
        } else {
            remotePath.add(DatacenterEnum.DHP.value());
        }

        return remotePath;
    }

    public static Set<String> getAllPaths(DataFlowEnum dataType) {
        Set<String> allPaths = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        String prefix = dataType.equals(DataFlowEnum.PARTIAL) ? DataFlowEnum.PARTIAL.value() : DataFlowEnum.TEMP.value();
        allPaths.add(prefix + LOCAL_PATH);
        for (String path : REMOTE_PATH) {
            allPaths.add(prefix + path);
        }
        return allPaths;
    }       

    private static final Optional<String> getHostNameOfServer() {
        try {
            return Optional.of(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName().toLowerCase());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            // logging error
            return Optional.absent();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isDevHost(String hostName) {
        return hostName.indexOf(".dev.") >= 0;
    }

    public static DatacenterEnum getCurrentDatacenter() {
        return ourLocation;
    }
}
```

And below is my `DataFlowEnum` which is also being used by other classes:

```
public enum DataFlowEnum {
    PARTIAL("/tr"), TEMP("/trpp");

    private String value;

    private DataFlowEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This is the way I am calling from my main application code to get all the paths:

```
Set<String> allPaths = DatacenterEnum.getAllPaths(key.Type());
```

Does my above code looks right or are there any chances of improvement in terms of efficiency and performance? This calculation should be only one time when the code is called for the first time instead of we are doing same thing for every call. My above code is generic, let's say if I want to add another datacenter, then I just need to add another datacenter in my above ENUM and it will work fine.

I also thought about doing through properties file as suggested by rolfl in my previous question, but in that case we still need to release a new version of client within our company for other customers so I am planning to go with this ENUM solution which is also generic, for any new datacenter, we can just add it and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Slight oddities

1. Your `enum` types do not need an `Enum` suffix in the name, calling them `Datacenter` or `DataFlow` should be clear enough. :)
2. I think your `VALUES` and `SIZE` are redundant, as you can call `values()` and `values().length` directly. Arguably, specifying `SIZE` is much shorter, but you'll have to use it often enough to 'see' the difference, and given the current code it's better off as a direct reference.
3. Your `static final` variables do not have a consistent casing, they should be `UPPERCASE`, therefore `random => RANDOM` and `ourLocation => OUR_LOCATION`. On the latter, maybe calling it `LOCALHOST` is a plausible option, since it references the host name of the current server?
4. How is `forCode()` used by the other classes? It's odd that you have a method that specifically expects callers to know the ordering of your `enum` values in order to retrieve the desired one... what if someone changes `LTR` to before `SLP` to order them alphabetically?
5. With the exception of the comments in `findLocation()`, I feel that the other comments are redundant as they explained the [*how* and not the *why*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90113/27975). The link tells you why (pun unintended) it should be the other way round. :) Even for `findLocation()`, you can probably simplify the comment to explain *why the random selection suffices* - is this a prior technical agreement? Recommended practice? Because the Benevolent <s>Dictator</s> Architect said so?
6. Do `isDevHost(String)` and `DataUtils.isProduction()` agree with, i.e. complements, each other? If so, there's a small simplification which I'll explain below.
7. Is the distinction for `LOCAL_PATH` and `REMOTE_PATH` purely for determining the arrangement in the `Set` when calling `getAllPaths(DataFlowEnum)`? If so, you can probably just determine the arrangement once upon initialization into a `List` so that you don't even need to make them `static final` references... will illustrate this below.
8. `getCurrentDatacenter()` can be dropped too, by making `OUR_LOCATION` `public`.

### Code Simplication

1. **`indexOf(CharSequence) >= 0`** can be replaced by `contains(CharSequence)`.
2. **You can *probably* simplify your constructor as such**, assuming the paths and naming conventions don't change:

   ```
   private Datacenter() {
       this.value = "/datacenter/" + name().toLowerCase();
   }
   ```

   The `String`s you use in your `enum` values' declaration are not required. You should also consider adding the `final` keyword to `value` too, to make it clear that it cannot be re-assigned.
3. **`findLocation()`**

   First, since you will always randomize a server or use `DHP` when `DataUtils.isProduction() == false`, you don't need the intermediate `return` statement after your `for` loop, retaining just the final one. Second, if `isDevHost(String)` complements `DataUtils.isProduction()`, then you don't even need the former (naturally), and you can also neatly skip that nested `if`. Combining both will result in the following simplification:

   ```
   private static Datacenter findLocation() {
       Optional<String> host = getHostNameOfServer();
       if (host.isPresent() && DataUtils.isProduction()) {
           for (Datacenter dc : values()) {
               if (host.get().contains("." + dc.name().toLowerCase() + ".")) {
                   return dc;
               }
           }
       }
       return DataUtils.isProduction() ? values()[RANDOM.nextInt(values().length)] : DHP;
   }
   ```

   One more thing: you can also consider making `"." + dc.name().toLowerCase() + "."` as your `enum`'s `toString()` representation.
4. **`findLocalPath()`**

   This can become the following one-liner: `return (DataUtils.isProduction() ? OUR_LOCATION : DHP).value();`
5. **`findRemotePath()`** (which should really be `findRemotePaths()`)

   To reduce one-level of nesting, you can consider testing for `DataUtils.isProduction()` first as such:

   ```
   private Set<String> findRemotePath() {
       if (!DataUtils.isProduction()) {
           return Collections.singleton(DHP.value());
       }
       Set<String> remotePaths = new HashSet<String>();
       for (Datacenter dc : EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(OUR_LOCATION))) {
           remotePaths.add(dc.value());
       }
       return remotePaths;
   }
   ```
6. **`getAllPaths(DataFlowEnum)`**

   `dataType.equals(DataFlowEnum.PARTIAL)` can simply be `dataType == DataFlowEnum.PARTIAL`. Actually, I'm not sure why you need the comparison, since you can just use it directly. You probably need a `null`-check here though, to avoid `NullPointerException`s. Effectively, you can just assign `String prefix = dataType.value();`.

   As mentioned above, you probably can consider determining the arrangement once upon initialization into a `List` to simplify the code:

   ```
   private static List<Datacenter> getOrdered() {
       // create a List by adding findLocation() first, then the other two
       // e.g. reuse EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(OUR_LOCATION)) here
   }

   private static final List<Datacenter> ORDERED = getOrdered();

   public static Set<String> getAllPaths(DataFlow dataType) {
       // null check first
       Set<String> allPaths = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
       for (Datacenter current : ORDERED) {
           allPaths.add(dataType.value() + current.value());
       }
       return allPaths;
   }
   ```
7. **`DataFlowEnum`**

   One small advice: add the `final` keyword to `value` to indicate that it cannot be re-assigned.
8. **Diamond (sign) for generics type inference**

   Just a general comment, if you are on Java 7, you can use [`<>` for generics type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html).

**edit** As requested, this is what a possible implementation for `getOrdered()` can look like:

```
private static List<Datacenter> getOrdered() {
    if (!DataUtils.isProduction()) {
        // if returning just DHP makes sense for non-prod environment
        // return Arrays.asList(DHP);
        // else replicate existing implementation
        return Arrays.asList(DHP, DHP);
    }
    EnumSet<Datacenter> local = EnumSet.of(getCurrentProdLocation());
    List<Datacenter> result = new ArrayList<Datacenter>(local);
    for (Datacenter dc : EnumSet.complementOf(local)) {
        result.add(dc);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have that chunk of comment at the start to highlight one thing: do you intentionally want your non-prod environment to have the same `DHP` value for both local and remote paths? Regardless whether that is a misunderstanding of the actual requirements, you can do the check `!DataUtils.isProduction()` and return the appropriate results for the non-production scenario first. As a result, you can skip the same check in `findLocation()` too (renaming it as `getCurrentProdLocation()`):

```
private static Datacenter getCurrentProdLocation() {
    Optional<String> host = getHostNameOfServer();
    if (host.isPresent()) {
        for (Datacenter dc : values()) {
            // assuming toString() representation is "." + dc.name().toLowerCase() + "."
            if (host.get().contains(dc.toString())) {
                return dc;
            }
        }
    }
    return values()[RANDOM.nextInt(values().length)];
}
```

Comment: Awesome code review. Thanks for the help. I was reading your point 6 in Code Simplification - Why you want to have `ORDERED` List? Can you fill that method as well as I am confuse how would that method will be used in `getAllPaths` then? Does that mean I will not use `findRemotePath()` method

Comment: @david the code for it will be close to putting both `findLocation()` and `findRemotePath()`, just that it returns a `List` in the ordering that you require. Yes, you will not require both the methods, and as well as `LOCAL_PATH` and `REMOTE_PATH` too. This is assuming you definitely do not need to expose them with the `public` access modifier down the road...

Comment: I see, can you fill that method as well just to make sure I understood this right? And then how ORDERED will be use then? getAllPaths method will change right?

Comment: @david please see my update... yes, `getAllPaths()` implementation will change.